# Error in Kendo UI with Angular-2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo UI in angular2 application, i have followed steps from this URL http://www.telerik.com/blogs/cooking-with-aspnet-core-and-angular-2, after running application in browser, its working fine but whenever i have added, kendo UI items like kendo grid/kendo buttons i am getting below error.

Trying to match the version of @progress with angular but not succeeded.

Could someone knows about this error?

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "@progress/kendo-data-query"
>  at webpackMissingModule (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10709:90)
>  at Object. (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10709:194)
>  at __webpack_require__ (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
>  at Object. (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:7664:29)
>  at __webpack_require__ (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
>  at Object. (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10766:23)
>  at __webpack_require__ (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
>  at Object._b (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:11091:21)
>  at __webpack_require__ (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
>  at Object. (D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:10027:28)
>  Current directory is: D:\DemoProject\ng2\kui2-aspnetcore
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+d__7.MoveNext()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred due to depending on which version of Kendo UI and Angular-2 we used, accordingly additional dependencies we should to mention/specify,

e.g. in above error kendo Ui version should be like this, 
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.13.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.10.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.3.0",
    "@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "^1.28.1",

below is the complete package.json file,

```
    {
  "name": "Angular2Spa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.13.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^0.10.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^0.3.0",
    "@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "^1.28.1",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.11",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "angular2-universal": "~2.0.11",
    "angular2-universal-patch": "^0.2.1",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.0.11",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.17",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.0.0-beta.13 || ^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "install": "^0.8.7",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "npm": "^4.3.0",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.37",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

Above change fixed my problem.